# ошибка в регулярном выражении, найти между тегов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Хочу получить содержимое между `</noindex></noindex> и <hr size="6" width="75%"><a name=\"followups\">`

Делаю так:

```
 </noindex>(?!</noindex>)([\s\S]|.*)<hr size="6" width="75%">\s+<a name=\"followups\">
```

Вот текст пример:

```
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="Gainsboro" link="Blue" alink="Purple" vlink="Purple" background="">
<h2 align=center>Вам не кажется что это похоже на?))</h2>

<noindex><center><hr size="6" width="75%">[<a href="#followups">Ответы и комментарии</a>] [<a href="" rel="nofollow">Развернуть ответы</a>] [<a href="">В закладки</a>] [<a href="">Написать ответ</a>]<br>
[<a href=""></a>] [<a href="">Архив</a>] [<a href="/boards/" rel="nofollow">Список</a>] <hr size="6" width="75%"></center></noindex><noindex>Отправлено: <a href="" rel="nofollow"></a>, 12.08.2015 01:17:11<br>
</noindex><ul><li><a target="_blank" href=""></a></ul><hr size="6" width="75%">
<a name="followups">Ответы и комментарии:</a><br><ul>
```

Но регулярка не срабатывает, предположительно из-за переносов

```
p = Pattern.compile("<\\/noindex>(?!\\s+<noindex>)([\\s\\S]*)<hr size=\"6\" width=\"75%\">\\s+<a name=\"followups\">");
```

Comment: Категорически не рекомендуется парсить HTML регулярками. Для этого есть парсеры.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, но тут нет явного вхождения в опредленный тег, до и после тега только, иначе как по другому спарсить все после  </noindex> и до <hr size="6" width="75%">, при этом учесть что они ближайшие к друг-другу, т.к.  </noindex> повторяется несколько раз вместе с <hr size="6" width="75%">

Comment: Насколько я понял из плохо отформатированного html-я вам надо просто содержимое UL тэга же...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб к сожалению контент динамический, может его и не быть, могут быть другие теги, может вообще ничего не быть между  </noindex> и <hr size="6" width="75%">

Comment: @aliokero А что значит "не срабатывает" ? Мне кажется она срабатывает, только берет слишком много ...

Comment: @aliokero Попробуйте: `<\/noindex>((?(?=<noindex>)|[\s\S])*)<hr size="6" width="75%">\s+<a name="followups">`, если поможет - ответ напишу.

Comment: @Mike не могу проверить регулярку на других онлайн сервисах, т.к. ведет себя очень странно. Ума не приложу, как можно получить содержимое после </noindex> и до <hr size="6" width="75%">, с учетом, что эти теги максимально приближенные и другие до и после них повторяющиеся нужно игнорировать, а содержимое между ними может быть текст или HTML с переводами строк.

Comment: @Mike , выдает Unknown inline modifier near index 14
<\/noindex>((?(?=<noindex>)|[\s\S])*)<hr size="6" width="75%">\s+<a name="followups">

Comment: @aliokero Вы же все `/` заэкранировали, полагаю ... жаль. значит движок регулярок в джаве не поддерживает условия ... подумаю как по другому ...

Comment: @aliokero А вот так: `(?:<noindex>[\s\S]*?<\/noindex>)++([\s\S]*?)<hr size="6" width="75%">\s+<a name="followups">` или `(?><noindex>[\s\S]*?<\/noindex>)+([\s\S]*?)<hr size="6" width="75%">\s+<a name="followups">` ?

Comment: @Mike спасибо, с регулярками не пойми что в Java, проще со строками работать, Ваш пример с ошибкой выходит всеравно. Остановился на варианте от ЮрийСПБ

Comment: @aliokero Жаль, судя по описанию джавовских регулярок должно было сработать, это сверхжадный захват. ну да ладно, если можно обойтись без сложной регулярке, то лучше так и сделать, быстрее работать будет :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String fullString = "<body text="#000000" bgcolor="Gainsboro" link="Blue" alink="Purple" vlink="Purple" background="">
<h2 align=center>Вам не кажется что это похоже на?))</h2>

<noindex><center><hr size="6" width="75%">[<a href="#followups">Ответы и комментарии</a>] [<a href="" rel="nofollow">Развернуть ответы</a>] [<a href="">В закладки</a>] [<a href="">Написать ответ</a>]<br>
[<a href=""></a>] [<a href="">Архив</a>] [<a href="/boards/" rel="nofollow">Список</a>] <hr size="6" width="75%"></center></noindex><noindex>Отправлено: <a href="" rel="nofollow"></a>, 12.08.2015 01:17:11<br>
</noindex><ul><li><a target="_blank" href=""></a></ul><hr size="6" width="75%">
<a name="followups">Ответы и комментарии:</a><br><ul>";

String cutedString = fullString.subString(0, fullString.lastIndexOf("</noindex>"));
cutedString = cutedString.subString(cutedString.lastIndexOf("</noindex>")+"</noindex>".lenght(), cutedString.lastIndexOf("<hr size="6" width="75%">"));
```

Comment: Тоже, думал про подстроку, но </noindex> встречается в тексте как писалось ранее несколько раз, а последний раз за пределами конструкции </noindex>(.*)<hr size="6" width="75%">

Comment: @aliokero, ну так а в чём проблема? Дополнил код убиранием последнего "</noindex>"

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался!